# String index out of bounds exception using chararray

Tags: java, arrays

the following code is supposed to convert phone number characters into the actual phone number integers. for example, 800-NEXT-DAY = 800-639-8329. But no matter what I enter into the `result.substring` index, I get the string index out of range section and i don't know why. Trying to figure out how to fix it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    String result = " ";
    System.out.print("Enter a phone number");
    String initialNumber = input.nextLine();

    for(char c: initialNumber.toLowerCase().toCharArray());
    switch(c){
    case '0':                                         result+="0";
    case '1':                                         result+="1";break;
    case '2': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':           result+="2";break;
    case '3': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':           result+="3";break;
    case '4': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':           result+="4";break;
    case '5': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':           result+="5";break;
    case '6': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':           result+="6";break;
    case '7': case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': result+="7";break;
    case '8': case 't': case 'u': case 'v':           result+="8";break; 
    case '9': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': result+="9";break;
    }
    String s1 = result.substring(0, 3);
    String s2 = result.substring(3, 6);
    String s3 = result.substring(6, 9);

    System.out.print(s1+s2+s3);
}}
```

Comment: Why are you breaking it up into three substrings that you're then just joining together anyway? Have you printed out `result` before taking the substrings? Which line fails? What is the value when it fails?

Comment: `for(char c: initialNumber.toLowerCase().toCharArray());`   a semicolon

Comment: @singhakash: The existing code wouldn't compile, in fact - unless there's also a static field called `c`. Yet another reason the question is bad :(

Comment: @JonSkeet substrings are joined in another way: CCC-XXX-YYYY

Comment: @SashaSalauyou: Not in the code provided. That may be the *intention*, but it's not what the code does. The code provided is basically equivalent to `System.out.println(result.substring(0, 9));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your semi colon at the end of your `for` loop ends your `for` loop. You do not want to end the `for` loop. Ending the for loop does not allow `result` to get updated with your switch statement causing `result` to still be `" "` when calling `result.substring`. Change your `;` to a `{`.

```
for(char c: initialNumber.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    switch(c){
    case '0':                                         result+="0";
    case '1':                                         result+="1";break;
    case '2': case 'a': case 'b': case 'c':           result+="2";break;
    case '3': case 'd': case 'e': case 'f':           result+="3";break;
    case '4': case 'g': case 'h': case 'i':           result+="4";break;
    case '5': case 'j': case 'k': case 'l':           result+="5";break;
    case '6': case 'm': case 'n': case 'o':           result+="6";break;
    case '7': case 'p': case 'q': case 'r': case 's': result+="7";break;
    case '8': case 't': case 'u': case 'v':           result+="8";break; 
    case '9': case 'w': case 'x': case 'y': case 'z': result+="9";break;
    }
}
```

Also add a `}` to the end. This solves the index out of bounds issue you are encountering.

Comment: appreciate the feedback. works like a charm now. & i originally had it in three results to include dashes between in the print, even though it wasn't included in the original code i entered. Turns out i didnt need it anyways.

Comment: @BenjaminDareEdwards Glad I was able to help. If you are satisfied with my answer could you accept it please.  Thanks. :)